# Updating data from Realtime database using getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, getserversideprops, getstaticprops

I have an application with markdown posts and comments taken from a Realtime Firebase database using getStaticProps.

At first, I get all of the paths:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const files = readdirSync('posts')

  const paths = files.map(fileName => ({
    params: {
      postname: fileName.replace('.md', '')
    }
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

And then I obviously get the markdown data along with the snapshot of the comments themselves:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { postname } }) {
  const fileName = readFileSync(`posts/${postname}.md`, 'utf-8')
  const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileName)
  const snapshot = await retrieveComments(postname).then(snapshot => {
    return { props: { snapshot } }
  })
  const slug = postname

  return {
    props: {
      frontmatter,
      content,
      snapshot,
      slug
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine when it comes to getting the markdown data, but the comments list never updates in the UI if I add a comment to the Realtime database and update the page. Everything worked fine when I used `getServerSideProps`. And remember that we cannot use both `getStatic...` and `getServerSide...`. What can I do? Also, this problem that the comments list never updates appears only in production.

`AND THE PROBLEM IS A HUNDRED PERCENT NOT IN THE CRUD OPERATIONS WITH THE DATABASE`

Answer (score 0):

The page is statically generated, so it will display the updated result only on next build. Assuming, you are getting updated data from server, you can [Use on demand revalidation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#using-on-demand-revalidation) when someone posts a comment:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    // This should be the actual path not a rewritten path
    // e.g. for "/blog/[slug]" this should be "/blog/post-1"
    await res.revalidate('/path-to-revalidate');
    return res.json({ revalidated: true });
  } catch (err) {
    // If there was an error, Next.js will continue
    // to show the last successfully generated page
    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating');
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, fam. But what do you mean by `/path-to-revalidate`?

Comment: the page path where data is shown

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't see the comment in the code. Sorry :)

Comment: No worries :). If this solved your issue, you can accept this answer by clicking ✅ icon besides it.

Comment: But how can I get the slug?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't update the comments list when I add a new one: https://imgur.com/a/4ib9WgR

Comment: Btw, here is what I have: https://imgur.com/a/hjbO2Ae.
The blog is about a mouse, btw